# Plotting CALIPSO backscatter data function of lat/long

Tags: python, plot

I am very new to python and am currently trying to plot CALIPSO backscatter data as a function of height and location rather than height and time. I am not sure where to begin as I am very new to this. 
Below is the code I am working with

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from ccplot.hdf import HDF
    from ccplot.algorithms import interp2d_12
    import ccplot.utils

    filename = '/CAL_LID_L1-ValStage1-V3-02.2012-12-01T04-24-22ZN.hdf'
    name = 'Total_Attenuated_Backscatter_532'
    label = 'Total Attenuated Backscatter 532nm (km$^{-1}$ sr$^{-1}$)'
    colormap = '/ccplot/cmap/calipso-backscatter.cmap'
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 1000
    h1 = 0  # km
    h2 = 20  # km
    nz = 500  # Number of pixels in the vertical.

    if __name__ == '__main__':
with HDF(filename) as product:
    # Import datasets.
    time = product['Profile_UTC_Time'][x1:x2, 0]
    height = product['metadata']['Lidar_Data_Altitudes']
    dataset = product[name][x1:x2]

    # Convert time to datetime.
    time = np.array([ccplot.utils.calipso_time2dt(t) for t in time])

    # Mask missing values.
    dataset = np.ma.masked_equal(dataset, -9999)

    # Interpolate data on a regular grid.
    X = np.arange(x1, x2, dtype=np.float32)
    Z, null = np.meshgrid(height, X)
    data = interp2d_12(
        dataset[::],
        X.astype(np.float32),
        Z.astype(np.float32),
        x1, x2, x2 - x1,
        h2, h1, nz,
    )

    # Import colormap.
    cmap = ccplot.utils.cmap(colormap)
    cm = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(cmap['colors']/255.0)
    cm.set_under(cmap['under']/255.0)
    cm.set_over(cmap['over']/255.0)
    cm.set_bad(cmap['bad']/255.0)
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(cmap['bounds'], cm.N)

    # Plot figure.
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    TIME_FORMAT = '%e %b %Y %H:%M:%S UTC'
    im = plt.imshow(
        data.T,
        extent=(mpl.dates.date2num(time[0]), mpl.dates.date2num(time[-1]), h1, h2),
        cmap=cm,
        norm=norm,
        aspect='auto',
        interpolation='nearest',
    )
    ax = im.axes
    ax.set_title('CALIPSO %s - %s' % (
        time[0].strftime(TIME_FORMAT),
        time[-1].strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
    ))
    ax.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax.set_ylabel('Altitude (km)')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.AutoDateLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
    cbar = plt.colorbar(
        extend='both',
        use_gridspec=True
    )
    cbar.set_label(label)
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('calipso-plot.png')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Obtain latitude/longitude information using:

   latitude  = product['Latitude'][x1:x2, 0]
   longitude = product['Longitude'][x1:x2, 0]
2. under # Plot Figure:

   im = plt.imshow(...,
                  extent=(latitude.min(), latitude.max(), h1, h2),
                  ...)
3. Comment out :

   ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(...)
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(...)

and replace with:

```
ax.xaxis.set_majot_locator(mpl.ticker.LinearLocator())
```

Have fun!